How to optimize performance with DeleteDuplicates?
Does anyone know how to improve this for speed performance? The code works fine, but DeleteDuplicates makes it really slow for large lists.
removeDuplicatesWithRules[mylist_] := Module[{rules, isDuplicateQ},
   
   rules = 
    Flatten /@ (Subsets[{{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, {3 -> 4, 4 -> 3}, {5 -> 6, 
         6 -> 5}, {7 -> 8, 8 -> 7}, {9 -> 10, 10 -> 9}}]);
   
   (*Function to check if two elements are considered duplicates \
based on rules*)
   isDuplicateQ[element1_, element2_] := 
    AnyTrue[rules, ((element1 /. #) /. 
         List :> Composition[Sort, List]) == (element2 /. 
         List :> Composition[Sort, List]) &];
   
   (*Function to remove duplicates from a list*)
   DeleteDuplicates[mylist, isDuplicateQ[#1, #2] &]
   
   ];

(*Example test list*)
mylist = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {5, 
    6, {8, 7, 1}}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 9}, {11, 12}};

(*Applying the function*)
removeDuplicatesWithRules[mylist]

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}} *)

Update:
I didn't check it carefully, and the current solution doesn't provide the correct result in some cases.
For example:
elm1 = {{2}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}};
elm2 = {{1}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}};

makestandard = i_?EvenQ :> (i - 1);
Equal @@ ({elm1, elm2} /. makestandard)

These two elements are not the same based on the list of rules above ((#1 /. a rule) = #2). makestandard makes them identical. However, there not exist any rule in rules that makes (elm1 /. a rule) = elm2.

I don't really understand your rule of duplicates, but removeDuplicatesWithRules seems to be the main reason for slowing down. DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ mylist] produces the same output, and runs much faster. Does that match your need?

@A.Kato nope, that is not the same.
Two elements are considered duplicate if  #1/. ruleX= #2 where ruleX could be any rule from rules. If you use Sort only, these two elements {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {5, 6, {8, 7, 1}} would not be duplicates.

I see. thank you.

FYI: DeleteDuplicates[data, sameFunc] has much worse performance than DeleteDuplicates[data] or DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, hashFunc] in general.

To clarify what you mean by updated question: for the input {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}}, your removeDuplicatesWithRules[ ] returns {{1, 2, 3}}. But there seems to be no rule which makes {1,2,3} and {3,2,1} are identical...

@internet If you think you checked an answer that is not correct you can uncheck it and then select other answer that is correct.

@A.Kato They are identical on its own if we ignoring the order. And if you talk about the rule, yes there is a rule {} which is actually does nothing but it does include that. This is not actually the issue I mentioned in the updated question.

@A.Kato Basically In checking duplicates, you are considering 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 are the same as 1, 3 ,5, 7, 9, respectively. this is where it leads to wrong result. This is not exactly equivalent to the duplicates that I mentioned in removeDuplicatesWithRules.

Using the definition I see `In[45]:= isDuplicateQ[{{2}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}}, {{1}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}}]
Out[45]= False`. Is that the intended behavior?

@DanielLichtblau Yes, that is intended as there is no rule that could turn one into the other.

(–1) By the amount of confusion among people trying to answer your question, you can see that it's very unclear. Please edit the question and make it clear what the expected behaviour is. Also include a few test cases.

In checking duplicates, you are considering 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 are the same as 1, 3 ,5, 7, 9, respectively.
Then, instead of testing all possible replacement, I recommend you to convert into standard forms:
mylist = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {5, 
    6, {8, 7, 1}}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 9}, {11, 12}}; 

makestandard = i_?EvenQ :> (i - 1);
DeleteDuplicatesBy[mylist, (# /. makestandard) &]

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}} *)


(+1) Also: DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, # /. i_?EvenQ :> i - 1 &]

That's a creative solution!

Not really unique enough to add as seperate answer, but you could also do DeleteDuplicatesBy[mylist, # + Mod[#, 2] &]

This is the way. In general: it's better to use DeleteDuplicatesBy and SortBy etc. if you can. These functions are almost always faster than the 2-arg forms of DeleteDuplicates and Sort et. al.

@SjoerdSmit This is the way to get wrong result faster than the correct one. Does anybody read the question, the first OP's comment under the question and also the update to the question?

@azerbajdzan That's why I said "IF YOU CAN". Of course not every problem can be handled this way. I will admit that I didn't look into the problem at hand here. But I do recommend to the OP to try and figure out if the problem can be rephrased as a DeleteDuplicatesBy problem because it's just much more intuitive to deal with.

I build upon A. Kato's idea to use a normalization: First turn each element into a unique representative of the equivalence class. Then run vanilla DeleteDuplicates. This guarantees that the default comparison function can be used, which I expect to be the fastest.
The small price to pay here is that the result does not look exactly as if just the first occurence of an element of an equivalence class would be kept.
I assume here that your list of rules consists of pairwise disjoint cycles of length 2. To normalize an element x, we loop over all cycles in the list of rules. For each cycle c we look for the first occurrence of one of its numbers and then apply or not apply this cycle to make this first occurrence be the first number in the cycle. If I am not mistaken, this define a unique respresentative for each equivalence class.
Here is the normalization function:
ClearAll[normalize];
normalize[x0_, cycles_] := Module[{x = x0, p},
   Do[
    p = FirstPosition[x, Alternatives @@ c];
    If[! MissingQ[p] && (! Extract[x, p] == c[[1]]),
     x = x /. {c[[1]] -> c[[2]], c[[2]] -> c[[1]]}
     ];
    , {c, cycles}];
   x
   ];

Here is a usage example:
cycles = {{9, 6}, {3, 10}, {4, 2}, {1, 5}, {7, 8}};

mylist3 = {
  {1, {2, 3, 2}, {{{3, 4}, 5, 1}, 6}, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
  {5, {2, 3, 2}, {{{10, 4}, 1, 5}, 6}, 4, 8, 7, 9, 10}, 
  {1, {4, 10, 4}, {{{10, 2}, 5, 1}, 9}, 2, 7, 8, 6, 3}
};

DeleteDuplicates[normalize[#, cycles] & /@ mylist3]


{{1, {4, 3, 4}, {{{3, 2}, 5, 1}, 9}, 2, 7, 8, 6,
10}, {1, {4, 3, 4}, {{{10, 2}, 5, 1}, 9}, 2, 7, 8, 6, 10}}

It seems to work also for the updated problem:
cycles = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

elm1 = {{2}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}};
elm2 = {{1}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}};

normalize[elm1, cycles] != normalize[elm2, cycles]


True

Disclaimer: I (maybe falsely) assumed that the ordering within each element mattered. This is might not be what OP ask for.

This answer is for the case where the order does matter. While OP's question asks for case where the order does not matter at any level.
First of all rules can be stored in a much more neat form.
Instead of OP's
(* rules = 
    Flatten /@ (Subsets[{{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, {3 -> 4, 4 -> 3}, {5 -> 6, 
         6 -> 5}, {7 -> 8, 8 -> 7}, {9 -> 10, 10 -> 9}}]); *)

we can use
rules = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

We define a function compare that can be used inside DeleteDuplicates.
compare[x_, y_, ru_] := 
 Block[{q, r = Sort /@ ru}, 
  MatchQ[Replace[{x, y}, Except[_List] -> Nothing, All], {p_, 
     p_}] && (q = Sort /@ Union@Transpose[Flatten /@ {x, y}]; 
    Union[Length /@ 
       Union /@ 
        Join[GatherBy[q, #[[1]] &], GatherBy[q, #[[2]] &]]] == {1}) &&
    ContainsAll[r, Sort /@ DeleteCases[q, {p_, p_}]]]

rules = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

mylist1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {5, 
    6, {8, 7, 1}}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 9}, {11, 12}};

DeleteDuplicates[mylist1, compare[#1, #2, rules] &]

mylist2 = {{{2}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}}, {{1}, {4, 5, 8, 
     9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}}};

DeleteDuplicates[mylist2, compare[#1, #2, rules] &]


{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, {7, 8, 2}}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}

{{{2}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}}, {{1}, {4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}}}

Different rules:
rules = {{9, 6}, {3, 10}, {4, 2}, {1, 5}, {7, 8}};

mylist3 = {{1, {2, 3, 2}, {{{3, 4}, 5, 1}, 6}, 4, 7, 8, 9, 
    10}, {5, {2, 3, 2}, {{{10, 4}, 1, 5}, 6}, 4, 8, 7, 9, 
    10}, {1, {4, 10, 4}, {{{10, 2}, 5, 1}, 9}, 2, 7, 8, 6, 3}};

DeleteDuplicates[mylist3, compare[#1, #2, rules] &]


{{1, {2, 3, 2}, {{{3, 4}, 5, 1}, 6}, 4, 7, 8, 9, 
  10}, {5, {2, 3, 2}, {{{10, 4}, 1, 5}, 6}, 4, 8, 7, 9, 10}}

